# Direct Update on txt Files

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing both `Android` and `iOS` B2C app (will upload it to Store). Reading from [here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-quickly-update-application/#advantagesAndRestrictions), it seems there are some restrictions for `Direct Update`.

```
 - The update is for the app web resources only
 - To update native resources, a new app version must be uploaded to the respective app store
 - Android: no restrictions
 - Windows Phone 8: no restrictions
 - iOS:
        B2C: according to the terms of service of your company; usually at least bug fixes are allowed
        B2E: through the iOS Developer Enterprise Program
```

But the requirement is:

- User want to update some .txt files in production without want to use `Adapter`.

Is this allowable and able to be done as in the doc saying for web resources only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how do you intend to use this "txt file" in the application but I am pretty sure you can classify it as a web resource without worries.

Comment: I will integrate with native to get the content of txt file I think.

Comment: Btw does the Web Resources mean the one that inside common folder or other environments folder?

Comment: Those end up to be one and the same web resources.